# MySQL DATA type int & varchar2

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table including following fields.

id, auto_no

02) I would like to update auto_no field with auto increment numbers like 2018-000001, 2018-000002, 2018-000003. What may be the data type I have to select for auto_no field.

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Have you tried `CONCAT` method?

Comment: @Kamaran. Can. But I need to insert this whole value to the auto_no field.

Comment: You can't use an integer type since your data contains the **"-"** character. So you should use VARCHAR or change the format of your data to 2018000001 (and use INT(10) type) or 2018.000001 (and use FLOAT(10,6)).